# How do I teleport to anywhere on the map with camera locked?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want move to anywhere on the map with the Teleport summoner spell. But I play with the camera locked on the champion. When I need see far details on the map, I click and hold the left mouse button on minimap. So the only way I found to teleport is unlock the camera (Y hotkey) and after the teleport lock again.

There is some simple method to teleport with camera locked or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: I tested Sight Wards and minions.  It only works with turrets. :)

Comment: I think that lockinging your camera is fundamentally wrong ;-) You are just jailing yourself into a bubble and you will miss a lot of important informations. If it can help you if you keep space bar pressed it will center the camera on you.

Comment: Why would you want the screen to stay focused on your character when you are teleporting? Isn't it better to see what's happening at your destination? That way you can plan ahead what your next move is going to be. For example, if you as Rammus teleport into a battle at Drake you have time to plan "i need to immediately flash to the north so that i can taunt their ad carry, or my team mate is going to die". If you leave your screen focused on your char when teleporting, you will need to waste a precious split second when you arrive on evaluating the situation and your next move.

Comment: If you like screenlocking your champion, but want to get better at LoL in general, try unlocking your camera and hold [spacebar]. [spacebar] is a soft screen lock (e.g. it locks the screeen for as long as you hold down [spacebar]. Use this to wean yourself from having it locked at all times! I use it myself from time-to-time, especially in certain situations or with certain champions (Singed being one), where softlocking occasionally (or during a teamfight) is highly beneficial.

Comment: @Hystic Sometimes players have physical disabilities and camera locking actually *enables* them to play the game. I have a friend who has one arm and he can play using a laptop's touchpad. Scrolling with the mouse, however, would be too difficult in-game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can teleport to a turret by clicking on its icon on the minimap.  This will *only* work with turrets, however.  I've just tested it on minions as well as `Sight Wards`, neither of which respond.  When you click `Teleport` and then hover over a turret, you will see the icon change from a light blue to a light green, indicating that it's a valid locatioln.